# Wix registry key changing

Tags: wix

I'm using a WiX installer file to edit a registry entry however when it's uninstalled I want it to be set do a default value of 0.

Here is the code I'm using to set it to 1.

```
  <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU"
               Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
        Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
    <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="DisableTaskMgr" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

I want it so that when it uninstalls that it does not delete the key but just sets it to 0 as I am unsure what the behaviour of the taskmanager would be if the key was deleted.

I'm also assuming Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" should be something else?

Comment: Also, I'm going to be adding a key to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] for it to start my app on startup. In that particular case I'm assuming that the "createAndRemoveOnUninstall" is exagtly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Action" has been deprecated and instead you should be using "ForceCreateOnInstall" and/or "ForceDeleteOnUninstall" instead.

You can also use "NeverOverwrite" on the component to make sure that the registry value isn't removed.

To set the value you can use a custom action that is scheduled to run only during the uninstall. Use NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE as the conditional for your custom action to ensure it only executes during uninstall.

For the custom action under Product AND Package add

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="YourCustomAction" After="InstallInitialize"><![CDATA[(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: I've never worked with .wxs files. I don't want to have to run a custom action if I can avoid it. Since this is suppose to write the key.

Comment: Right so essentially just changing that to ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" should do the trick. Is there not a similar way to just edit the registry back without doing a custom action? I have C# code which writes to the registry that I did try to create a custom action with the following guide : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx However I got stuck because my wix file did not have a <InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: I edited my response to include the InstallExecuteSequence you'll want to place under the Product

Comment: You're a star, but just like my previous InstallExecuteSequence placing it within the product tag vs screams an error :( http://i.imgur.com/YhNokp9.png - You answer has also been accepted as the original question is answered.

Comment: please ignore that last comment. Placing the InstallExecuteSequence towards the end of the Product tag fixes the issue. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what I get for doing a quick glance at documentation, InstallExecuteSequence comes after Product AND Package. I'll update my response to clarify.